# Unable to update the Curl on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, versions, curl

I am trying to uprade my curl version from 7.46.0, however, after numerous try the version still remains the same.

```
root@Ubuntu:~# curl --version
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2n zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.37.0-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

I have tried everything available on the internet to no luck;

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then tried the below update.

```
root@Ubuntu:~# sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8).
```

May be there are some libraries I need unlink/link, however, I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you installed the 7.46 curl without using `apt`. What does `which curl` output?

Comment: Hi @sharangkaul, have you tried uninstalling it completely, and then reinstalling it?

Comment: root@Ubuntu:~# which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl

root@Ubuntu:~# /usr/local/bin/curl --version
curl 7.46.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.46.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2n zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.37.0-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets


# I have updated ubuntu from 16.xx to 18.04
# I did try to install curl completely following articles. However, noticed even after the curl was uninstalled, the curl related commands still worked. 
# I have used apt

Comment: Follow these instructions: https://yannmjl.medium.com/how-to-manually-update-curl-on-ubuntu-server-899476062ad6